# Append overwrites every element with last appended value (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to prepare list of lists containing all possible parameters combinations which will be used in brute-force search. The parameters combinations should look like this:

[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0.2, 0.8]
[0.2, 0, 0.8]
...
[0.4, 0.4, 0.2]
...
[1, 0, 0]

The code generating these lists works just fine - printing *weights_temp* in every iteration returns correct results. However there is some problem with appending. When I print *weights*, all I get is this (last *weights_temp* value instead of other elements):

[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
...
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
...
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]

This is my code:

```
step = 0.2

weights_temp = [0, 0, 1]
weights = [weights_temp]

i = 1

while weights_temp != [1, 0, 0]:
    # decrease gamma
    weights_temp[2] = 1 - i * step

    for j in xrange(0, i + 1):
        # increase alpha, decrease beta
        weights_temp[0] = j * step
        weights_temp[1] = abs(1 - weights_temp[2]) - j * step

        weights.append(weights_temp)

        print weights_temp

    i += 1
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `weights.append(weights_temp)` is appending the same thing every time since weights_temp, to my knowledge, is a reference/pointer to the data. ie, instead of appending a new list and changing that list, you are appending the same reference and changing the data at that reference everytime. if you print `weights` whenever you append, you will probably see that every list is being updated every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing with my comment, instead of adding a reference, make a new list every time you add with list comprehension.

```
weights.append([item for item in weights_temp])
```

Example:

```
>>> temp = [1,2,3]
>>> holder = [temp]
>>> holder
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> temp[0] += 1
>>> holder
[[2, 2, 3]]
>>> holder.append([item for item in temp])
>>> holder
[[2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
>>> temp[0] +=1
>>> holder
[[3, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for s in arr:
li.append(
    {"id":s.get("InstanceId"),"Message":s.get("Status").get("Message") }
 )
```

Comment: Welcome. Please be sure to include an explanation, not just code.